# Validity of 10 yr EU resident card if living outside of EU for more than 1 yr

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, france, eu, residence-cards

I have a question regarding the validity of a "Carte de résident de Longue durée-UE" (10 yr EU resident card) that is issued recently in France.
I understand that the card is no longer valid if one leaves France for a period of 6 consecutive years. However, I was wondering whether the card would still be valid if one leaves France now and works in the UK (which is not a part of the EU anymore) for the next 2-3 yrs and comes back to France?
Does anyone have any experience?

Answer (score 2):

Article 9 of [Directive 2003/109/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32003L0109) provides that

> 1. Long-term residents shall no longer be entitled to maintain long-term resident status in the following cases:
>
> […]
>
> (c) in the event of absence from the territory of the Community for a period of 12 consecutive months.

That means that you can leave in any case go to the UK for 12 months and come back to France without losing your status.

The French rules offer more flexibility. According to [demarches.interieur.gouv.fr](https://www.demarches.interieur.gouv.fr/particuliers/carte-resident-longue-duree-ue-etranger-france-ans)

> Votre carte de résident de longue durée - UE ne doit pas être périmée. La carte est périmée si vous êtes dans l'une des situations suivantes :
>
> - Vous avez résidé en dehors du territoire des pays membres de l'Union européenne pendant une période de plus de 3 ans consécutifs
>   […]

So you can go for 2 years to the UK but you would risk losing your status if you go over the 3-year mark.

The 6-year rule only applies if you stay out of France but still within the EU. It's designed to let you gain a new long-term resident EU status elsewhere in the EU without risking your status in the first country.